External hardware recommendations to cool down small MS “2-in-1” laptop, that is fanless
I have a small Microsoft Surface Pro, that I sometimes use myself, let kids use, etc.
It’s a tiny, not-very-powerful thing, that has its components inside the screen region — so basically a tablet with a magnetically clip on keyboard — did I mention that it is completely fanless? No cooling whatsoever.
But the problem is, because its processors are relatively powerful, it overheats really, really fast when using it.
What hardware external product (general product or specific brand) would you recommend to help cool the MS surface pro?
Price isn’t a factor.

In general you will want to choose between a "tablet cooling stand" and a "tablet cooling fan".
I recommend something like this tablet stand that has multiple fans and adjustable fan speed, but it requires you to put the tablet down.
If you want to keep the tablet cooled while holding it, look for a solution like this magnetic fan.

Thanks- great answer!
